# How to read a file each n characters instead of each line using awk?

Tags: linux, bash, file, optimization, awk

This is the content of `file.txt`:

```
hello bro
my nam§
is Jhon Does
```

The file could also contain [non-printable characters (for example \x00, or \x02)](https://shop.alterlinks.com/ascii-table/ascii-ebcdic-us.php), and, as you can see, the lenght of the lines are not the same.

Then I want to read it each each 5 characters without having into a count line breaks. I thought in something like this using awk:

```
awk -v RS='' '{
  s=s $0;
}END{
  n=length(s);

  for(x=1; x<n; x=x+5){
    # Here I will put some calcs and stuff

    i++;
    print "line " i ": #" substr(s,x,5) "#"
  }
}' file.txt
```

The output is the following:

```
line 1: #hello#
line 2: # bro
#
line 3: #my na#
line 4: #m§
is#
line 5: # Jhon#
line 6: # Does#
```

It works perfectly, but the input file will be **very** large, so the performance is important.

In short, I'm looking for something like this:

```
awk -v RS='.{5}' '{ # Here I will put some calcs and stuff }'
```

But it doesn't works.

Another alternative that works ok:

```
xxd -ps mifile.txt | tr -d '\n' | fold -w 10 | awk '{print "23" $0 "230a"}' | xxd -ps -r
```

Do you have any idea or alternative? Thank you.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you'd like to use awk? Does `fold -w 5 file.txt` give you the output you expect?

Comment: Yes, I have to work with each part of file in the awk, and if I use the fold command that you've posted, besides it does not return the desired ouput -look at the breakline after `bro`, then the awk couldn't know when starts and ends the "line". I explain?

Comment: Whats up with `~` ? Also what do you mean read in 5 characters? read in and do what with them,just print them out again ?

Comment: You need to show us the exact desired output because at the moment it's not clear.

Comment: The `~` is the way I use to load the entire file (becouse it doesn't contains any `~`. In the loop I'll have to work with them, not only printing (I decided to omit it because it is not relevant).

Comment: Is that the desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you want but this outputs the same as the script in your question that you say works perfectly so hopefully this is it:

```
$ awk -v RS='.{5}' 'RT!=""{ print "line", NR ": #" RT "#" }' file
line 1: #hello#
line 2: # bro
#
line 3: #my na#
line 4: #m§
is#
line 5: # Jhon#
line 6: # Does#
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use perl and binmode assuming you are using normal characters.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'test'; 
#open the file.
binmode $fh;
# Set to binary mode
$/ = \5;
#Read a record as 5 bytes

while(<$fh>){
#Read records
        print "$_#"
        #Do whatever calculations you want here
}
```

For extended character sets you can use UTF8 and read every 5 characters instead of bytes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<:utf8', 'test';
#open file in utf8.
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
# Set stdout to utf8 as well

while ((read($fh, my $data, 5)) != 0){
#Read 5 characters into variable data
    print "$data#";
    #Do whatever you want with data here
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @123! But I'm afraid the file wich I have to work could contain some non-printable characters. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with ***Python***, You may try this

```
f = open('filename', 'r+')
w = f.read(5)
while(w != ''):
        print w;
        w = f.read(5);
f.close()
```

Comment: Auch, and there is no way to read the `§` as one character? Look at the alternative I've added in the main post, please.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't realize. Works ok!

Answer (score 1):

So you asked How to read a file each n characters instead of each line **using awk**.

*Solution*:

If you have a modern `gawk` implementation use [FPAT](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html#Splitting-By-Content)

> Normally, when using FS, gawk defines the fields as the parts of the
>   record that occur in between each field separator. In other words, FS
>   defines what a field is not, instead of what a field is. However,
>   **there are times when you really want to define the fields by what they
>   are**, and not by what they are not.

Code:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FS="\n";RS="";FPAT=".{,5}"}
            {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++){
               printf("$%d = <%s>\n", i, $i)}
            }' file
```

Check the [demo](http://ideone.com/8xzOH9)

Comment: Wow! Looks great! But I'm afraid it skips the linebreak. Look at the line 3 of my example, it has 5 chars, the fith is linebrack. Thanks!

Comment: That reads blocks and will still break, and even if it didn't OP says their input file is very large, so reading it all into memory is likely not an option.

Comment: Yep, i missed the *very large* part .. deal with the linebreaks in `awk`  then not gonna worth the effort

Comment: And what about the alternative that I've post at the end of the question? maybe a little tricky...

Comment: That does not respond to  how to do it using **just awk**.